# Remote application sharing tool used at ASP.NET MVC podcasts

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, sharing, remote-access

Does anybody know what tool used while podcasts were recorded here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/application-development/

For example at lesson #17 (with Atwood)

The sample of what i'm talking about you can see at 6m28s at the window title, near minimize/maximize/close button. There is a green circle with "Currently sharing"

Cannot google anything relevant, so will be appreciate for your help ;-)

**UPD**: anyone? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Windows Meeting Space.  I've never used it so I don't know for sure.

See Figure 12 here:
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Using-Windows-Meeting-Space.html

If you look closely at the screenshot you can see the green dot and "Currently Sharing" in the title bar of Paint.